# How to gradually remove nodes from the graph

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a graph that consists of one central node and a large number of other nodes connected to the central one. I'd like to remove nodes in a transactional fashion, i.e. start with outer nodes, remove them in batches of, say, 5K each and proceed moving towards center.

Here is a console link that contains a small exemplary graph http://console.neo4j.org/?id=vwphbn for reference.

My problem is to match for nodes that don't have relationships other that the one connecting them (indirectly) with the central node.

Upd. I think some explanation will help. I have a large hierarchical dataset, which I need to delete in chunks, but since the conventional way (repeating this:

```
MATCH (n: Root {rootId : {rootId}})
OPTIONAL MATCH n-[r]-x
DELETE r,x
RETURN count(*)
```

while `count > 0`) may cause deletion of the `Root` itself and some child nodes will be left orphaned with no means to detect and delete them, I think, there should be some way in which I still can delete chunks of the graph more or less cheaply, while at the same time having some ordering and retaining the cornerstone - root node.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using your example graph, the following query will prune the graph in batches as expected:

```
MATCH p=(n1:Node)<-[r*]-(n2)
WHERE NOT (n2)<--()
WITH last(nodes(p)) AS n
LIMIT 5000
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
DELETE r, n
```

It's worth noting that the first `MATCH` statement in this query will cause performance issues at scale. To resolve this, you can apply a label to all the nodes that are connected to the root node and then do the following:

```
MATCH (n1:Nodes)
WHERE NOT (n1)<--()
LIMIT 5000
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
DELETE r, n
```

This will only delete nodes layer by layer. Meaning that if you ran this query multiple times, it will delete a portion of the last layer, then in the next query a portion of the next inner layer as well as the last outer layer.

Update:

Also if you were to go slice by slice, this query would delete one slice at a time:

```
MATCH p=(n1:Node)<-[r*]-(n2)
WHERE NOT (n2)<--()
WITH nodes(p) AS slices
LIMIT 1 UNWIND slices AS n
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
DELETE r, n
```

Comment: The thing is there are more than on such 'circles' in the database, so I can't actually match just by label. But you inspired me to devise another approach, which is delete entities not in this 'concentric' way, but rather in a way similar to how you would slice a pie: match a bunch of paths `MATCH (r:Root)-[rel]-(n), p=((n)-[r*]-(k))`, and then delete `rel` and `p`, which will leave me with the root itself after all the 'slices' have been 'cut'. Is this approach worth trying? And since p will match all the paths like `(a)`, `(a)--(b)`, `(a)--(b)--(c)` etc., maybe it's better to...

Comment: ... to collect all the nodes from paths, do `DISTINCT` on them and then remove them inside a `FOREACH` block?

Comment: I really like that idea. Here is the query I would recommend using UNWIND:

MATCH p=(n1:Node)<-[r*]-(n2)
WHERE NOT (n2)<--()
WITH nodes(p) AS slices
LIMIT 1 UNWIND slices AS n
MATCH (n)-[r]->()
DELETE r, n

Comment: Wow! I did totally miss the `UNWIND` clause.  This is really neat! Thank you for your time :)